# TI ARM CLANG wont resolve symbol even though objdump shows its there

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang

I am trying to compile my code on CCS(Code composer studio) using TI ARM CLANG compiler.

I am trying to implement Ethernet fucntionality which uses TI's enet SDK

I call a fucntion in my main which is in the enet SDK but the comiler is throwing error

> unresolved symbol Enet_initOsalCfg(EnetOsal_Cfg_s, first referenced in *)

I have added its library in the linker tab

To confirm i am not doing something stuipd I use same compilers objdump to disassemble the library and I think if I am not mistaken the dump clearly shows the symbol is present.

Function I called in main() has the declaration:

```
void Enet_initOsalCfg(EnetOsal_Cfg *osalCfg);
```

Following is a snippet from the objdump having same name as my function:

```
Disassembly of section .text.Enet_initOsalCfg:

00000000 <Enet_initOsalCfg>:
       0: 00 48 2d e9   push    {r11, lr}
       4: 08 d0 4d e2   sub sp, sp, #8
       8: 04 00 8d e5   str r0, [sp, #4]
       c: 04 00 9d e5   ldr r0, [sp, #4]
      10: fe ff ff eb   bl  #-8 <Enet_initOsalCfg+0x10>
      14: 08 d0 8d e2   add sp, sp, #8
      18: 00 88 bd e8   pop {r11, pc}

Disassembly of section .rel.text.Enet_initOsalCfg:

00000000 <.rel.text.Enet_initOsalCfg>:
       0: 10 00 00 00   andeq   r0, r0, r0, lsl r0
       4: 1c 9c 00 00   andeq   r9, r0, r12, lsl r12

Disassembly of section .ARM.exidx.text.Enet_initOsalCfg:

00000000 <.ARM.exidx.text.Enet_initOsalCfg>:
       0: 00 00 00 00   andeq   r0, r0, r0
       4: 01 00 00 00   andeq   r0, r0, r1

Disassembly of section .rel.ARM.exidx.text.Enet_initOsalCfg:

00000000 <.rel.ARM.exidx.text.Enet_initOsalCfg>:
       0: 00 00 00 00   andeq   r0, r0, r0
       4: 2a 72 00 00   andeq   r7, r0, r10, lsr #4
```

What am I missing here?

Excuse me if I am being stupid

Comment: Did you include the header provided with the library?  Is it intended for use with C++ or only C?  I am wondering about something like a missing `extern "C"`.  A [mcve] would help.  Also, is that really the entire error message from the linker?

Comment: You were right my friend I forgot that the SDK was in C and my code is in C++, I dont know how did I miss that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big oops our friend in the comments found my problem. I forgot extern "C" sorry for being stupid I was scratching my head on this since 4 hours, my aplologies :P

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).